# Using if else statement in Linq Query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I am using following linq query to work with XML file..

```
XElement rootElement = XElement.Load(@"test.xml"); 
int StyCode; 
var lv1s = from lv1 in rootElement.Descendants("Class") 
where lv1.Attribute("Code").Value.Equals("002") 
select new 
{ 
Children = from ltd in lv1.Descendants("Subject") 
where ltd.Attribute("Course").Value.Equals("Math") 
select new 
{ 

****//In This below section need result on condition based... ****
if(StyCode=0)  
{
Children1 = ltd.Attribute("AllTeachers").Value.Equals("Y") ? true : false
}
else
{
Children2 = ltd.Attribute("SpeciaGuest").Value.Equals("Y") ? true : ltd.Elements("Topic").Attributes("Code").Where(x => x.Value.Equals("1")).FirstOrDefault() != null ? true : false 
}
} 
};
```

Below is my XML Structure..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Document>
  <Class Code="001">
    <Subject Course="Math" AllTeachers='N' SpeciaGuest='N'></Subject>
    <Subject Course="Engish" AllTeachers='Y' SpeciaGuest='Y'></Subject>
    <Subject Course="History" AllTeachers='Y' SpeciaGuest='Y'></Subject>
  </Class>
  <Class Code="002">
    <Subject Course="Math" AllTeachers='Y' SpeciaGuest='N'>
      <Topic Code="1">LAW1</Topic>
      <Topic Code="2">
        LAW2
      </Topic>
      <Topic Code="3">
        LAW3</Topic>
      </Subject>
    <Subject Course="Engish" AllTeachers='Y' SpeciaGuest='Y'></Subject>
    <Subject Course="History" AllTeachers='Y' SpeciaGuest='Y'></Subject>
  </Class>
</Document>
```

Please let me know, how I can use condition to select multiple select result. Also let me know using resharper in this linq query will be fine?.

Comment: The two don't have the same type.  One is a `string`, and one is a `boolean`.  They'll need to have the same type for this to work.  They should also realistically have the same name, or else you'd never be able to use either of them.

Comment: @Servy : Modified the code..

Comment: You only addressed one of the two issues I mentioned.  Also note that your `if` isn't based on the item, it's based on a value outside the scope of the query, so just pull the `if` outside of the query as well.

Comment: Yes I know this if and else is wrong place, but I don't know perfectly about out side the code,because if I will place this condition above the query then I hope we need to use same query for if & else ?? I am still new in linq so please suggest.

Comment: There is never any reason to write `? true : false`.  You already have a boolean.

Comment: Your XML as written currently has a number of errors.  It has an unmatched closing `</State>` tag; it has `<Topic>` matched with `</County>`; and there is a `<Subject Course="Math".. >` with no matching close tag.

Comment: @Saks : if I am not going to write ? true : false for Children so it giving error and I am agree with Servy's words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `if(StyCode=0)` isn't based on the current item in the sequence, you can pull the `if` outside of the query:

Also note that because both of the `Select` clauses are selecting a single item, you don't need an anonymous type, just select that item.  That results in this:

```
XElement rootElement = XElement.Load(@"test.xml");
int StyCode = 0;
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<bool>> lv1s;
if (StyCode == 0)
{
    lv1s = from lv1 in rootElement.Descendants("Class")
            where lv1.Attribute("Code").Value.Equals("002")
            select (from ltd in lv1.Descendants("Subject")
                    where ltd.Attribute("Course").Value.Equals("Math")
                    select ltd.Attribute("AllTeachers").Value.Equals("Y") ? true : false);
}
else
{
    lv1s = from lv1 in rootElement.Descendants("Class")
            where lv1.Attribute("Code").Value.Equals("002")
            select (from ltd in lv1.Descendants("Subject")
                    where ltd.Attribute("Course").Value.Equals("Math")
                    select ltd.Attribute("SpeciaGuest").Value.Equals("Y") ? true : ltd.Elements("Topic").Attributes("Code").Where(x => x.Value.Equals("1")).FirstOrDefault() != null ? true : false);
}
```

So this is simple, and nice, but has a lot of code duplication, which is not no nice.  Another road to travel down is to create a method that takes an `XElement` that represents `ltd` as well as an integer `StyCode` and returns a boolean indicating the appropriate value.  It's a simple enough method to write:

```
private static bool GetChildFromSubject(int styCode, XElement subject)
{
    if (styCode == 0)
        return subject.Attribute("AllTeachers").Value.Equals("Y");
    else
    {
        return subject.Attribute("SpeciaGuest").Value.Equals("Y") ||
                subject.Elements("Topic").Attributes("Code")
                .Any(x => x.Value.Equals("1"));
    }
}
```

Now we only need one query:

```
XElement rootElement = XElement.Load(@"test.xml");
int StyCode = 0;
var lv1s = from lv1 in rootElement.Descendants("Class")
            where lv1.Attribute("Code").Value.Equals("002")
            select (from ltd in lv1.Descendants("Subject")
                    where ltd.Attribute("Course").Value.Equals("Math")
                    select GetChildFromSubject(StyCode, ltd));
```

Much better.

Comment: Thanks Servy,This is much better code & if you have any better linq reference or coding guideline please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create anonymous objects with different properties. What would sequence type be then? You can assign different values to same property (via ternary operator `?:`)

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"test.xml");

var lv1s = from c in xdoc.Descendants("Class")
           where (string)c.Attribute("Code") == "002"
           select new {
               Children = (StyCode == 0) ? 
                          ((string)c.Attribute("AllTeachers") == "Y") :
                          ((string)c.Attribute("SpeciaGuest") == "Y") ||
                            c.Elements("Topic")                                 .
                             .Any(t => (string)t.Attribute("Code") == "1"))
           };
```

BTW what you are returning is list of objects with boolean `Children` property. I believe you need more data in result.

Answer (score 1):

```
bool flag = boolexpression ? true : false;
```

is the same as

```
bool flag = boolexpression;
```

So, stop using the ternary to needlessly complicate your code.

---

You can write your select clause as:

```
select new 
{ 
  Children1 = (StyCode==0) ? ltd.Attribute("AllTeachers").Value.Equals("Y") : false,
  Children2 = (StyCode==0) ? false :
     ltd.Attribute("SpeciaGuest").Value.Equals("Y")
     || ltd.Elements("Topic").Attributes("Code").Where(x => x.Value.Equals("1")).FirstOrDefault() != null
}
```

---

Some might say that repeating the condition is bad form.  If you are in that camp, I recommend using this instead:

```
select (StyCode == 0) ? objectContructor1(ltd) : objectConstructor2(ltd)
```

Comment: But at a time I want to return one result either Children1 or Children2 Based on my if and else condition

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the conditional operator:

```
Children1 = StyCode == 0 ? 
    ltd.Attribute("AllTeachers").Value == "Y"
:
   (ltd.Attribute("SpeciaGuest").Value == "Y"
 || ltd.Elements("Topic").Attributes("Code").Select(a => a.Value).Contains("1")
    )
```